# шаблон category.php

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть страница со всеми категориями. Мне нужно чтобы когда я нажал на категорию у меня открылось страница со списком всех постов из категории которую я нажал.-я создал template category.php, Ho какой код Я должен вести в эту страницу чтобы при нажатии вывести название категории + список всех постов из этой категории B category.php.

Answer (score 0):

у меня они выводятся так

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="cat">
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        "category_name" => get_queried_object()->name,
        'numberposts' => 20
    ));

    foreach( $posts as $post ){
        setup_postdata($post);

        ?>
        <a class="cat_ins" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h2><?php get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>


        <?php
    }

    wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
    ?>
```